# getFilePath API of FilePart not working as expected

Tags: java

I am working on a webbased application with servlets and JSPs in it. My requirement is to get the  path of a file which is uploaded in my application.

The legacy code used to get the name of the file by using the code -

//FilePart class of the com.oreilly.servlet.multipart package.//

```
   FilePart filePart = (FilePart) part;
   screenosInputFileName = filePart.getFileName();
```

The getFileName returns the name of the file correctly as a string like "a.txt". Since I want the path also, I am using getFilePath as in--
        String path = filePart.getFilePath();

However, I find that getFilePath is only returning the file name and not the file path. That is, getFileName and getFilePath are returning the same value "a.txt". What I was expecting from getFilePath was something like c:\myfiles.
  Also, I am running my application in an Ubuntu enviroment (a linux flavour).

Any ideas why getFilePath is retuning only the filename and not the file path ? And how to overcome the problem. Any pointers higly appreciated.

Comment: you want file path from client ? then you can't do it like this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am not familiar with `com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.FilePart`.

If `FilePart` represents the file *on the client*, then it is impossible to get the path of it (there is no reason for a server to know whether `a.txt` was uploaded from `C:\Users\bob\` or from `/home/bob/Documents/`, so that information is not included).

If `FilePart` represents the file *on the server* (if your server saves uploaded files to a temporary directory so that you may access them as actual files), then you should be able to use this to get the actual path to the file:

```
String path = new File(filePart.getFilePath()).getAbsolutePath();
```

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: `FilePath` is a server component... the `servlet` in the package name was a big hint here.

Comment: @Bemrose I understand that. However, does this server component represent an object on the client or the server?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that Internet Explorer would include the full path of the file on the client's computer. I don't know if it does that anymore, but i don't think so, because it's a privacy issue. The server has no business knowing the full path.

Answer (score 0):

`getFilePath` is only going to work if the client is using Internet Explorer, as it's the only browser that returns the entire file path to the server.  Chances are, it'll only work with IE6 at that, as I believe MS finally realized this wasn't a good security practice when IE7 came out.